# Gradle project does not export implementation-dependency to other projects

Tags: java, gradle

My gradle project contains 3 sub-projects with one source file each:

```
root-project\
    sub-project-abstract\
        ...AbstractFoo.java
    sub-project-commons\
        ...ConcreteFoo.java (extends AbstractFoo)
    sub-project-main\
        ...Main.java (instantiates ConcreteFoo)
```

build.gradle of `sub-project-commons`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(:sub-project-abstract))
}
```

build.gradle of `sub-project-main`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(:sub-project-commons))
}
```

The Main-class in `sub-project-main` is aware of `ConcreteFoo`, however, **compilation fails with `cannot access AbstractFoo`**.

For some reason, I expected `sub-project-commons` to "export" `ConcreteFoo` **and** `AbstractFoo`, since it's a implementation-dependency. Or in other words, form the perspective of `sub-project-main`, `AbstractFoo` is a transitive dependency.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case.
I know that I could probably make it work by explicitly adding `sub-project-abstract` as a direct dependency to `sub-project-main`. However, that's something I want to avoid due to the nature of the commons project (my actual project contains up to 10 subprojects, and it should be possible to reuse the commons-project without declaring a dependency to `sub-project-abstract` every single time the commons-project is referenced.

Is there a way to make the Main-class aware of `AbstractFoo` without directly declaring `sub-project-abstract` as a dependency (but indirectly via `sub-project-commons`)?

Comment: The `implementation` configuration specifically does _not_ make the dependency of project X visible to any other projects which themselves depend on project X. Apply the [Java Library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugin and use the `api` configuration.

Comment: @Slaw ah, you are right. My impression was that `java-library` is not the right tool for the job if I don't want to publish an actual library to the outside world, but I was obviously wrong about that. If you add your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior for the `implementation` configuration. You should apply the [Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) and use the `api` configuration.

> The key difference between the standard Java plugin and the Java Library plugin is that the latter introduces the concept of an *API* exposed to consumers. A library is a Java component meant to be consumed by other components. **It’s a very common use case in multi-project builds** *[emphasis added]*, but also as soon as you have external dependencies.
>
> The plugin exposes two [configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:what-are-dependency-configurations) that can be used to declare dependencies: `api` and `implementation`. The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the `implementation` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Dependencies appearing in the `api` configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers. Dependencies found in the `implementation` configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath. *[...]*

In `sub-project-commons` (Kotlin DSL):

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...

    `java-library`
}

...

dependencies {
    api(project(":sub-project-abstract"))
}

...
```